# What method is needed to find records with differing fields that occur a set number of times?

Tags: mysql, join, count

I need to find the names of suppliers who have supplied to 2 or more different shops.
I have two tables. Suppliers, and Shops.

- Suppliers (SuppCode, SuppName)
- Shops (ShopCode, StockNo, Description, SuppCode)

I understand that I have to find the number of different ShopCodes that appear next to the SuppCode in the records, and if that number is 2 or greater, then display the SuppName.

Here is some code I've written that gets all of the supplier names and shop codes querying both tables:

```
SELECT SUPPNAME, SHOPCODE
FROM SUPPLIERS, SHOPS
WHERE SUPPLIERS.SUPPCODE = SHOPS.SUPPCODE;
```

How would I go about finding records with appear two or more times? I thought of using the COUNT() function but I haven't really got anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you will need to use the aggregate `COUNT()`.  It will need to go in a `HAVING` clause, which filters for groups `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SHOPCODE) >= 2`.  `DISTINCT` is needed so that the total number of different `SHOPCODE`s is counted instead of the total number of records.

It's necessary to use `HAVING` (as opposed to `WHERE`) because the `GROUP BY` aggregation is applied after a `WHERE` clause but you need to further limit the result of the aggregation.

```
SELECT
  SUPPNAME
FROM
  SUPPLIERS
  INNER JOIN SHOPS ON SUPPLIERS.SUPPCODE = SHOPS.SUPPCODE
GROUP BY SUPPNAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SHOPS.SHOPCODE) >= 2
```

A couple of points to note: I replaced your implicit inner join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) with an explicit one, which is a more modern syntax.  Since you only requested supplier names, only `SUPPNAME` appears in the `SELECT` list.  Finally, to make the aggregation work correctly, a `GROUP BY SUPPNAME` is necessary.

Here's a little demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/870e96/1

The same query using your implicit join looks like:

```
SELECT
  SUPPNAME
FROM
  SUPPLIERS,
  SHOPS 
WHERE SUPPLIERS.SUPPCODE = SHOPS.SUPPCODE
GROUP BY SUPPNAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SHOPS.SHOPCODE) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY` along with your query like

```
SELECT SUPPNAME, SHOPCODE
FROM SUPPLIERS, SHOPS
WHERE SUPPLIERS.SUPPCODE = SHOPS.SUPPCODE
GROUP BY SHOPS.SUPPCODE
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```